# Fastest way to solve non-negative linear diophantine equations

Tags: co.combinatorics, diophantine-equations, combinatorial-optimization, computer-algebra, integer-programming

Let $A$ be a matrix in $M_{n \times m}(\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0})$ without zero column. Let $V$ be a vector in $\mathbb{Z}_{> 0}^m$.

**Question**: What is the fastest way to find all the solutions $X \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}^n$ of the equation $AX=V$?
By non-negativity and "without zero column" assumption, it always has only finitely many solutions.

Note that the *usual* functions for solving such a system *may* underuse the non-negativity. To prove so, I wrote a naive code finding all the solutions of such a system and applied it to an example (see below and [this crosspost](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/62717/fastest-way-to-solve-non-negative-linear-diophantine-equations) on ask.sagemath), but I'm still looking for something significantly faster than this.

---

**Example**

Here is the kind of system I need to solve (where  $x_i \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$), but with possibly more equations and variables.

```
[
5*x0 + 5*x1 + 5*x2 + 6*x3 + 7*x4 + 7*x5 == 24,
5*x1 + 7*x10 + 5*x6 + 5*x7 + 6*x8 + 7*x9 == 25,
5*x11 + 6*x12 + 7*x13 + 7*x14 + 5*x2 + 5*x7 == 25,
5*x12 + 6*x15 + 7*x16 + 7*x17 + 5*x3 + 5*x8 == 30,
5*x13 + 6*x16 + 7*x18 + 7*x19 + 5*x4 + 5*x9 == 35,
5*x10 + 5*x14 + 6*x17 + 7*x19 + 7*x20 + 5*x5 == 35,
5*x1 + 7*x10 + 5*x6 + 5*x7 + 6*x8 + 7*x9 == 25,
5*x21 + 5*x22 + 6*x23 + 7*x24 + 7*x25 + 5*x6 == 24,
5*x22 + 5*x26 + 6*x27 + 7*x28 + 7*x29 + 5*x7 == 25,
5*x23 + 5*x27 + 6*x30 + 7*x31 + 7*x32 + 5*x8 == 30,
5*x24 + 5*x28 + 6*x31 + 7*x33 + 7*x34 + 5*x9 == 35,
5*x10 + 5*x25 + 5*x29 + 6*x32 + 7*x34 + 7*x35 == 35,
5*x11 + 6*x12 + 7*x13 + 7*x14 + 5*x2 + 5*x7 == 25,
5*x22 + 5*x26 + 6*x27 + 7*x28 + 7*x29 + 5*x7 == 25,
5*x11 + 5*x26 + 5*x36 + 6*x37 + 7*x38 + 7*x39 == 24,
5*x12 + 5*x27 + 5*x37 + 6*x40 + 7*x41 + 7*x42 == 30,
5*x13 + 5*x28 + 5*x38 + 6*x41 + 7*x43 + 7*x44 == 35,
5*x14 + 5*x29 + 5*x39 + 6*x42 + 7*x44 + 7*x45 == 35,
5*x12 + 6*x15 + 7*x16 + 7*x17 + 5*x3 + 5*x8 == 30,
5*x23 + 5*x27 + 6*x30 + 7*x31 + 7*x32 + 5*x8 == 30,
5*x12 + 5*x27 + 5*x37 + 6*x40 + 7*x41 + 7*x42 == 30,
5*x15 + 5*x30 + 5*x40 + 6*x46 + 7*x47 + 7*x48 == 35,
5*x16 + 5*x31 + 5*x41 + 6*x47 + 7*x49 + 7*x50 == 42,
5*x17 + 5*x32 + 5*x42 + 6*x48 + 7*x50 + 7*x51 == 42,
5*x13 + 6*x16 + 7*x18 + 7*x19 + 5*x4 + 5*x9 == 35,
5*x24 + 5*x28 + 6*x31 + 7*x33 + 7*x34 + 5*x9 == 35,
5*x13 + 5*x28 + 5*x38 + 6*x41 + 7*x43 + 7*x44 == 35,
5*x16 + 5*x31 + 5*x41 + 6*x47 + 7*x49 + 7*x50 == 42,
5*x18 + 5*x33 + 5*x43 + 6*x49 + 7*x52 + 7*x53 == 48,
5*x19 + 5*x34 + 5*x44 + 6*x50 + 7*x53 + 7*x54 == 49,
5*x10 + 5*x14 + 6*x17 + 7*x19 + 7*x20 + 5*x5 == 35,
5*x10 + 5*x25 + 5*x29 + 6*x32 + 7*x34 + 7*x35 == 35,
5*x14 + 5*x29 + 5*x39 + 6*x42 + 7*x44 + 7*x45 == 35,
5*x17 + 5*x32 + 5*x42 + 6*x48 + 7*x50 + 7*x51 == 42,
5*x19 + 5*x34 + 5*x44 + 6*x50 + 7*x53 + 7*x54 == 49,
5*x20 + 5*x35 + 5*x45 + 6*x51 + 7*x54 + 7*x55 == 48
]
```

Here are explicit $A$ and $V$ from above system (in list form):

```
A=[  
[5,5,5,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,5,0,0,0,0,5,5,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,5,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,5,0,0,0,0,5,5,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,5,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,6,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,7,7,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,7,7,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,7,7,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,7,7,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,7,7]  
]

V=[24,25,25,30,35,35,25,24,25,30,35,35,25,25,24,30,35,35,30,30,30,35,42,42,35,35,35,42,48,49,35,35,35,42,49,48]
```

---

**Computation**

I wrote a naive code finding all the solutions of such a system, then applied it to A, V above. It took 41 seconds to find all 5499 solutions. I'm looking for something significantly faster than this.

```
sage: %time LX=NonnegativeSolverPartition(A,V)
CPU times: user 40.7 s, sys: 0 ns, total: 40.7 s
Wall time: 40.9 s
sage: len(LX)
5499
```

---

**Code**

Here is my (python) code:

```
import copy

def NonnegativeSolverPartition(A,V):
    global LX
    WB=WeakBasis(A)
    VB=VarBound(A,V)    
    m=len(A[0])
    PP=[]
    LX=[]
    Or=[]
    c=0
    for l in WB:
        [i,ll]=l
        L=[A[i][j] for j in ll]
        B=[VB[j] for j in ll]
        n=V[i]
        P=WeightedPartitionSolver(L,B,n)        
        Or.append([len(P),c])
        c+=1
        PP.append(P)
    Or.sort()
    for i in range(len(Or)):
        if Or[i][0]!=1: 
            break
    ii=Or[i][1]
    for p in PP[ii]:
        X=[-1 for i in range(m)]
        PPP=copy.deepcopy(PP)
        PPP[ii]=[p]
        Fi=Filter(PPP,X,WB)
        if Fi!=[]:  
            [PPPP,XX]=Fi
            NonnegativeSolverPartitionInter(A,V,PPPP,WB,VB,XX)
    return LX
    
def NonnegativeSolverPartitionInter(A,V,PP,WB,VB,X):
    global LX
    Or=[[len(PP[i]),i] for i in range(len(PP))]
    Or.sort()
    c=0     
    for i in range(len(Or)):
        if Or[i][0]!=1:
            c=1 
            break
    ii=Or[i][1]
    if c==0:
        if -1 in X:
            print('problem: -1 in X')
        else:
            if V==[sum([A[i][j]*X[j] for j in range(len(A[0]))]) for i in range(len(A))]:
                LX.append(X)
    else:
        for p in PP[ii]:
            PPP=copy.deepcopy(PP)
            PPP[ii]=[p]
            Fi=Filter(PPP,X,WB) 
            if Fi!=[]:
                [PPPP,XX]=Fi
                NonnegativeSolverPartitionInter(A,V,PPPP,WB,VB,XX)

def WeakBasis(A):
    n=len(A)
    m=len(A[0])
    L=[]; F=[]
    for i in range(n):
        FF=[]
        for j in range(m):
            if A[i][j]!=0:
                FF.append(j)
        F.append(FF)        
    for j in range(m):
        LL=[]
        for i in range(n):
            if A[i][j]!=0:
                LL.append([len(F[i]),i])
            else:
                LL.append([0,i])
        LL.sort(reverse=true)
        L.append(LL[0])
    return [[i,F[i]] for i in range(n)] 

def VarBound(A,V):
    M=[]
    n=len(A)
    m=len(A[0])
    for j in range(m):
        N=[]
        for i in range(n):
            if A[i][j]!=0:
                N.append(V[i]//A[i][j])
        M.append(min(N)+1)
    return M

def WeightedPartitionSolver(L,B,n): # the entries of L must be non-negative
    global P        #B for upperbound coming from other equations (see VarBound)
    P=[]
    l=len(L)
    S=[0 for i in range(l)]
    m=n//L[0]+1
    for i in range(min(m,B[0])):
        S[0]=i
        WeightedPartitionSolverInter(L,B,n-L[0]*i,1,S)
    return P

def WeightedPartitionSolverInter(L,B,n,j,S):
    global P
    l=len(L)
    if j==l:
        if n==0:
            P.append(S)
    else:
        if n==0:
            P.append(S)
        else:
            m=n//L[j]+1
            for i in range(min(m,B[j])):
                SS=copy.deepcopy(S)
                SS[j]=i
                WeightedPartitionSolverInter(L,B,n-L[j]*i,j+1,SS)

def Filter(PP,X,W):
    if [] in PP:
        return []
    XX=copy.deepcopy(X)
    LL=[]
    for i in range(len(PP)):
        P=PP[i]
        F=FixedPoints(P)
        Wi=W[i]
        for j in F:
            P0j=P[0][j]
            Wij=Wi[1][j]
            if XX[Wij]==-1:
                XX[Wij]=P0j
            elif XX[Wij]!=P0j:
                return []
    for i in range(len(PP)):
        L=[]
        P=PP[i]
        Wi=W[i]
        lP0=len(P[0])
        for p in P:
            c=0
            for j in range(lP0):
                Wij=Wi[1][j]    
                if XX[Wij]!=-1:
                    if p[j]!=XX[Wij]:
                        c=1
                        break
            if c==0:
                L.append(p)
        if L==[]:
            return []
        LL.append(L)
    if [PP,X]==[LL,XX]:
        return  [LL,XX]
    else:
        return Filter(LL,XX,W)

def FixedPoints(P):
    m=len(P)
    n=len(P[0])
    if m==1:
        return [i for i in range(n)]
    F=[]
    for i in range(n):
        c=0
        for j in range(m):
            if P[j][i]!=P[0][i]:
                c=1
                break
        if c==0:
            F.append(i)
    return F
```

Comment: The code can certainly be optimised. E.g. the entire `j` loop of `WeakBasis` inefficiently (`max` is faster than reverse-sort-and-take-first) computes a series of values which then aren't used at all.

Comment: And none of those deep copies appear to need to be more than shallow copies, which for me halves the running time.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: I agree for S and X (list of int), but it seems unsafe to me to use a shallow copy for PP (list of list of list of int).

Comment: Most of those lists shouldn't actually be lists because, once initialised, they're immutable. [This is a more Pythonic version of your code](https://gist.github.com/pjt33/936c83fd312c61fe74ed0b08eec04b7d) with one additional optimisation: `VarBound` doesn't just compute a bound but an intersection of possible values. The next step up would be to filter in both directions, getting something along the lines of Knuth's "dancing links" algorithm. IIRC there is something about multiset cover in the latest fascicle of book 4b that I've seen.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Very good! A Cythonic version could be 10 times faster, isn't it?

Comment: It takes about 3.5 seconds in PyPy3 on tio.run.

Answer (score 3):

Consider *constraint programming* for this.  On my laptop, the constraint programming solver in SAS finds all the solutions in one second.

Code:

```
proc optmodel;
   var X {0..55} >= 0 integer;
   con
      5*X[0] + 5*X[1] + 5*X[2] + 6*X[3] + 7*X[4] + 7*X[5] = 24,
      5*X[1] + 7*X[10] + 5*X[6] + 5*X[7] + 6*X[8] + 7*X[9] = 25,
      5*X[11] + 6*X[12] + 7*X[13] + 7*X[14] + 5*X[2] + 5*X[7] = 25,
      5*X[12] + 6*X[15] + 7*X[16] + 7*X[17] + 5*X[3] + 5*X[8] = 30,
      5*X[13] + 6*X[16] + 7*X[18] + 7*X[19] + 5*X[4] + 5*X[9] = 35,
      5*X[10] + 5*X[14] + 6*X[17] + 7*X[19] + 7*X[20] + 5*X[5] = 35,
      5*X[1] + 7*X[10] + 5*X[6] + 5*X[7] + 6*X[8] + 7*X[9] = 25,
      5*X[21] + 5*X[22] + 6*X[23] + 7*X[24] + 7*X[25] + 5*X[6] = 24,
      5*X[22] + 5*X[26] + 6*X[27] + 7*X[28] + 7*X[29] + 5*X[7] = 25,
      5*X[23] + 5*X[27] + 6*X[30] + 7*X[31] + 7*X[32] + 5*X[8] = 30,
      5*X[24] + 5*X[28] + 6*X[31] + 7*X[33] + 7*X[34] + 5*X[9] = 35,
      5*X[10] + 5*X[25] + 5*X[29] + 6*X[32] + 7*X[34] + 7*X[35] = 35,
      5*X[11] + 6*X[12] + 7*X[13] + 7*X[14] + 5*X[2] + 5*X[7] = 25,
      5*X[22] + 5*X[26] + 6*X[27] + 7*X[28] + 7*X[29] + 5*X[7] = 25,
      5*X[11] + 5*X[26] + 5*X[36] + 6*X[37] + 7*X[38] + 7*X[39] = 24,
      5*X[12] + 5*X[27] + 5*X[37] + 6*X[40] + 7*X[41] + 7*X[42] = 30,
      5*X[13] + 5*X[28] + 5*X[38] + 6*X[41] + 7*X[43] + 7*X[44] = 35,
      5*X[14] + 5*X[29] + 5*X[39] + 6*X[42] + 7*X[44] + 7*X[45] = 35,
      5*X[12] + 6*X[15] + 7*X[16] + 7*X[17] + 5*X[3] + 5*X[8] = 30,
      5*X[23] + 5*X[27] + 6*X[30] + 7*X[31] + 7*X[32] + 5*X[8] = 30,
      5*X[12] + 5*X[27] + 5*X[37] + 6*X[40] + 7*X[41] + 7*X[42] = 30,
      5*X[15] + 5*X[30] + 5*X[40] + 6*X[46] + 7*X[47] + 7*X[48] = 35,
      5*X[16] + 5*X[31] + 5*X[41] + 6*X[47] + 7*X[49] + 7*X[50] = 42,
      5*X[17] + 5*X[32] + 5*X[42] + 6*X[48] + 7*X[50] + 7*X[51] = 42,
      5*X[13] + 6*X[16] + 7*X[18] + 7*X[19] + 5*X[4] + 5*X[9] = 35,
      5*X[24] + 5*X[28] + 6*X[31] + 7*X[33] + 7*X[34] + 5*X[9] = 35,
      5*X[13] + 5*X[28] + 5*X[38] + 6*X[41] + 7*X[43] + 7*X[44] = 35,
      5*X[16] + 5*X[31] + 5*X[41] + 6*X[47] + 7*X[49] + 7*X[50] = 42,
      5*X[18] + 5*X[33] + 5*X[43] + 6*X[49] + 7*X[52] + 7*X[53] = 48,
      5*X[19] + 5*X[34] + 5*X[44] + 6*X[50] + 7*X[53] + 7*X[54] = 49,
      5*X[10] + 5*X[14] + 6*X[17] + 7*X[19] + 7*X[20] + 5*X[5] = 35,
      5*X[10] + 5*X[25] + 5*X[29] + 6*X[32] + 7*X[34] + 7*X[35] = 35,
      5*X[14] + 5*X[29] + 5*X[39] + 6*X[42] + 7*X[44] + 7*X[45] = 35,
      5*X[17] + 5*X[32] + 5*X[42] + 6*X[48] + 7*X[50] + 7*X[51] = 42,
      5*X[19] + 5*X[34] + 5*X[44] + 6*X[50] + 7*X[53] + 7*X[54] = 49,
      5*X[20] + 5*X[35] + 5*X[45] + 6*X[51] + 7*X[54] + 7*X[55] = 48;
   
   solve with clp / findallsolns;
quit;
```

Log:

```
NOTE: Problem generation will use 4 threads.
NOTE: The problem has 56 variables (0 free, 0 fixed).
NOTE: The problem has 0 binary and 56 integer variables.
NOTE: The problem has 36 linear constraints (0 LE, 36 EQ, 0 GE, 0 range).
NOTE: The problem has 216 linear constraint coefficients.
NOTE: The problem has 0 nonlinear constraints (0 LE, 0 EQ, 0 GE, 0 range).
NOTE: The CLP solver is called.
NOTE: All possible solutions have been found.
NOTE: Number of solutions found: 5499.
NOTE: PROCEDURE OPTMODEL used (Total process time):
      real time           1.26 seconds
      cpu time            1.26 seconds
```

Answer (score 3):

Such problems are naturally expressed as finding integral points within a bounded polyhedron. There is a bunch of software available for this, e.g., [Normaliz](https://www.normaliz.uni-osnabrueck.de/). Although my initial attempt to employ Normaliz has failed (see ask.sagemath for detail), it *should* be some manageable issue, which I'm figuring out.

Meanwhile, with the help of Sage's `WeightedIntegerVectors` machinery, the bruteforce solution can be streamlined and simplified as follows:

```
def brutesol(A, V, row=0, freecols=None):
    n = A.nrows()   # number of equations
    m = A.ncols()   # number of variables

    if freecols is None:
        freecols = set(range(m))

    while row < n:
        cols = [c for c in freecols if A[row,c]!=0]
        if len(cols)!=0:
            break
        if V[row]!=0:
            return      # no solutions
        row += 1

    if row==n:
        yield {}
        return

    B = A[:,cols]

    for w in WeightedIntegerVectors(V[row], [A[row,c] for c in cols]):
        U = V - B*vector(w)
        if min(U) >= 0:
            for u in brutesol(A,U,row+1,freecols-set(cols)):
                u.update(zip(cols,w))
                yield u
    return
```

`brutesol` relies on linear algebra and assumes that `A` and `V` are a matrix and a vector, respectively. E.g., for counting solutions it can be called as

```
sum(1 for s in brutesol(matrix(A),vector(V)))
```

**UPDATE.** As for the polyhedral framework, I have learned that the bottleneck there is the construction of polyhedron (namely, computing its vertices), which is a prereq for computing integral points. The issue may be alleviated in Normaliz with implementation of a new algorithm, but it's not there yet.

On a general note, the problem represents a variant of a [multi-dimensional knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Multi-dimensional_knapsack_problem), and so it's unlikely to have an algorithm that would work efficiently in all the cases.

Comment: What did you figure out?

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux: Yes, see update.

Comment: Can we expect the existence of an algorithm significantly faster than brute-force (by using polyhedral idea or something else)? I definitely need a way, as fast as possible, to find all the solutions of such non-negative linear diophantine equations.

Comment: Someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72628766/fastest-way-to-solve-non-negative-linear-diophantine-equations#comment128293954_72628766) suggested to use numpy. What about that?

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux: It depends what you mean under *significantly*. E.g., I'd not expect a breakthrough from polyhedral computations, but it *should* be a solid and suitably efficient approach to get solutions here. But a brute force approach exploiting the features of the problem may do a good job here as well.

As for numpy, it's just a technical suggestion that may or may not improve performance of your approach a bit. I believe, Sage does use numpy internally.

Comment: Someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72628766/fastest-way-to-solve-non-negative-linear-diophantine-equations?noredirect=1#comment128307165_72628766) suggests to directly use a native language like C++. What about that?

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux: Again, using C++ or alike is a technical thing. It may give you some-fold speed up, but would not allow scale up much by itself.